# NUnit Test Adapter and NUnit both discovering and running tests

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, nunittestadapter

I have the NUnit test adapter (3.X) installed and my test project references NUnit (3.8.0.0). However, I'm seeing duplicate tests discovered (during build) and run by the NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0 **and** NUnit 1.2.0.0. What could be causing this? I can't work out where NUnit 1.2.0.0 is coming into this.

Comment: Do you have the older NUnit Visual Studio extension 1.2 installed as an extension or as a NuGet package for one of your projects? If you update it to the latest version, it will stop detecting the newer NUnit 3 tests.

Comment: Yes, but the package was not installed in the test project. I had to restart Visual Studio to get it to work. Thanks!